# remove object from parse json using value

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

i am pushing data into array and after json parse array look like.
using Array push

```
    itens_arr.push(JSON.stringify({
             id_item: $item_id,
             quantity: $item_quantity,
             assembly: assemble_val,
             unassembly:disassemble_val
           }));
 $.cookie("itens", itens_arr);
```

save value into cookies

at the remove function

```
var get_parse =JSON.parse($.cookie("itens"));
alert(get_parse)
```

get below value

```
{"id_item":"43","quantity":"2","assembly":1,"unassembly":0},{"id_item":"41","quantity":"3","assembly":1,"unassembly":0}
```

**for remove i use this code. but not working**

```
  var filtered = get_parse.id_item.filter(function(item) { 
           return item.id_item !== remove_val;  
        });
```

but how to remove full object,in my case i want to remove full object base on "id_item" value

Comment: "array look like" — That's missing the `[` and `]`

Comment: What is `get_parse`? What is `remove_val`?

Comment: Try providing a full [mcve], preferably as a [live demo](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: get_parse array name  and remove_val is id_item value like 43

Comment: please do not push stringified values to an array. you may stringify the array later for using it in a cookie, and parse it before using the array.

Comment: if i remove stringify in push time it did not return.

Comment: alert(JSON.stringify($.cookie("itens"))); in remove function retrun "[object][object]" not return proper json object

Answer (score 1):

You need to iterate the data array and test for the right value.

```js
var data = [{ id_item: "43", quantity: "2", assembly: 1, unassembly: 0 }, { id_item: "41", quantity: "3", assembly: 1, unassembly: 0 }],
    remove_val = '41',
    filtered = data.filter(function(item) {
        return item.id_item !== remove_val;
    });
        
console.log(filtered);
```

Comment: Wtf are the downvotes for?  This is correct.  I guess the downvoters don't understand the question.

Comment: but my value form push array and json data

Comment: @jhon, please provide the data in the structure, you have.

Answer (score 0):

**First**

You provided 2 objects and not array. `[]` are missing. Be sure that you have an array.

**Second**

Your `remove_val` should be a string because your objects id_item are string.

```js
const get_parse = [{
    "id_item": "43",
    "quantity": "2",
    "assembly": 1,
    "unassembly": 0
  },
  {
    "id_item": "41",
    "quantity": "3",
    "assembly": 1,
    "unassembly": 0
  }
];
const remove_val = "43";
console.log(get_parse.filter(d=>d['id_item']!==remove_val));
```

Comment: i am push data into array so what's array problem

Comment: You were using `get_parse.id_item` you need to filter the array `get_parse.filter()`

Comment: itens_arr.push(JSON.stringify({
         id_item: $item_id,
         quantity: $item_quantity,
         assembly: assemble_val,
         unassembly:disassemble_val
       }));
        //itens_arr.push({$item_id:data_arr});
        //
        $.cookie("itens", itens_arr);

Comment: @jhon I don't understand what you are trying to say. Please be clearer

Comment: i am updating problem please review it. hope you will understood better this time.

Answer (score 0):

```
    You can use $.grep , make sure you have use '[]' brackets


var my = [{ "id_item": "43", "quantity": "2", "assembly": 1, "unassembly": 0 } , { "id_item": "41", "quantity": "3", "assembly": 1, "unassembly": 0 }]
        var data = $.grep(my, function (e) {
            return e.id_item != 43;
        });
        console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Some observations :**

- get_parse should be an `array` because `itens` contains an `array of objects` not a `single` objects.

  Hence, get_parse should be like this.

  ```
  [{"id_item":"43","quantity":"2","assembly":1,"unassembly":0},
  {"id_item":"41","quantity":"3","assembly":1,"unassembly":0}]
  ```
- Array [**filter()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method works on an `array` not on a `string`. It will create a new array with all elements that pass the test implemented by the provided function.

  Hence, If you will try to filter the string(`get_parse.id_item`) it will give the below error

  > Uncaught TypeError: get_parse.id_item.filter is not a function

**Try this :**

```js
var get_parse = [{"id_item":"43","quantity":"2","assembly":1,"unassembly":0},
        {"id_item":"41","quantity":"3","assembly":1,"unassembly":0}]

var remove_val = "43";

var filtered = get_parse.filter(function(item) { 
           return item.id_item !== remove_val;  
        });

console.log(filtered);
```